# Python: combination to/from natural number mapping, how to scale up?

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

The problem is: combination to/from natural number mapping, the cobmination is to divide 1 (100%) by k and allocate k-tiles to n bins. Bins are stocks actually, so called weight set: a set of all possible weight tuples, or combinations and count is C(n+k-1,n-1) (starts and bars), and I want map them to/from natural numbers. I have attached the code at the bottom, here's the usage of it:

```
[in]
# from <wherever> import WeightSet
weight_set1 = WeightSet(10,3)
print(weight_set1.weight_tuple_cnt)
print(weight_set1.weight_tuple_from_id[20])
print(weight_set1.weight_id_from_tuple[0.1,0.8,0.1])
[out]
66
(0.1, 0.8, 0.1)
20
```

I enumerate out all weight tuples by moving the k-tiles from left to right one by one and this code works fine with k<=10, but if k>=20, it goes forever and memory usage hikes to near 100%. Is there a way to get the expected results without enumerating all weight tuples first? Please kindly advise.

```
from bidict import bidict
# 2024-02-04 WeightSet
class WeightSet:
    def __init__(self, k, n):
        self._k = k
        self._n = n
        next_weight_list = [0]*n
        next_weight_list[0] = k
        all_weight_tuples = {}
        weight_tuple_cnt = 1
        
        while True:
            all_weight_tuples[weight_tuple_cnt] = tuple(next_weight_list)
            next_found = False    
        
            first_nonzero_pos = next((pos_i for pos_i, value_i in enumerate(next_weight_list) \
                                      if value_i>0), None)
        
            if first_nonzero_pos < n-1:
                next_weight_list[first_nonzero_pos+1] += 1 
                next_weight_list[first_nonzero_pos] -= 1 
                rem_weight = next_weight_list[first_nonzero_pos] 
                if first_nonzero_pos>0 and rem_weight >0:
                    next_weight_list[0] = rem_weight
                    next_weight_list[first_nonzero_pos] = 0
        
                weight_tuple_cnt += 1
                next_found = True
            
            if not next_found: break

        self._weight_tuple_cnt = weight_tuple_cnt

        all_weight_tuples.update((x, tuple(z/k for z in y)) for x, y in all_weight_tuples.items())
        
        all_weight_tuples_bidict = bidict(all_weight_tuples)
        self._weight_tuple_from_id = all_weight_tuples_bidict
        self._weight_id_from_tuple = all_weight_tuples_bidict.inverse

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self._n

    @property
    def k(self):
        return self._k

    @property
    def weight_tuple_cnt(self):
        return self._weight_tuple_cnt
    
    @property
    def weight_tuple_from_id(self):
        return self._weight_tuple_from_id

    @property
    def weight_id_from_tuple(self):
        return self._weight_id_from_tuple
```

I have written the code as above, and it works fine for k<=10 but not k>=20.

Comment: Please provide all necessary `import` statements. Code as is does not compile.

Comment: sory, it's:
from bidict import bidict
I have fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Please put `import` into the code. It will be nice if you mention `bidict` in the text of question. Also, you said that "it works fine for k<=10 but not k>=20."  What  happens for ` 10 < k <20`?

Comment: I have added import into the code, I can see it, can you check again?
As for 10<k<20, if k=12 and n=6, it runs for a while, but the bigger k is, the longer it goes, but it seems to go forever beyond k=20. Since this is not the logic that doesn't work, it's about the time to enumerate all the combinations, so we can calculate the count with the formula of combinations and see the complexity. Hope this clarifies, thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in all the algorithms related to "integer partition" that are implemented in library sympy. Basically you're asking for the number of ways to partition k into n parts.

Comment: Also this could help for `weight_tuple_cnt`: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908701/integer-partition-of-n-into-k-parts-recurrence

Comment: *" Is there a way to get the expected results without enumerating all weight tuples first?"* << Yes, I'm almost certain there is. At the very least, one thing I can think of is to do a binary search. For instance, define a function `tuple_count(k, n, m)` that returns the number of partitions of k into n bins with no more than m per bin. Then do something like `def jth_tuple(k, n, j): x = k // 2; a = tuple_count(k-x, n-1, k); b = tuple_count(k, n, x-1); if j <= a: return (x, *jth_tuple(k-x, n-1, j)); else: return jth_tuple(k, n, j-a)`

Comment: The suggestion about sympy and integer partition is interesting, I will spend time to study and see how to tailor it toward my specific problem, namely, composition of non-negative number and specific number of blocks (bins, n in my case), thanks.

Comment: The algorithm with binary search and likely recursion seem to be the right direciton for me, I will study it and see if I can solve it, thanks a lot.

Comment: (Note that the code I wrote in my previous comment is most definitely wrong, but the idea is there)

Comment: As for sympy, they have many classes and functions related to integer partition, set partition, and multiset partition, but I've always found their documentation a bit of a pain to search through. Whenever I have a problem related to partitions, I basically re-read the documentation of every function that uses the word "partition" in its description, and try to find if one of them is related to my problem. That's a very slow and annoying process.

Comment: (In my code above, I at least made an error when I wrote `else: return jth_tuple(k, n, j-a)`, which cannot be correct; additionally, the way I cut between `tuple_count(k-x, n-1, k)` on the left and `tuple_count(k, n, x-1)` on the right is completely arbitrary and might not correspond to the order of tuples that you had in mind, if you had a particular order in mind; other ways to cut are likely possible)

Comment: Found it!!! [Find the nth integer composition with a fixed number of components in lexicographical order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227315/find-the-nth-integer-composition-with-a-fixed-number-of-components-in-lexicog)